# Деформация секции виджетов в шаблоне WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, шаблоны

Нашёл один шаблон который очень нравится и менять его не хочется совсем, но в нём есть косяк. Точнее, я не знаю, он появился по моей вине в результате неаккуратной правки шаблона или же был изначально и я его не сразу заметил.

Суть вот в чём: при просмотре поста в блоге, виджеты в футере располагаются нормально, как и должно быть. т.е. вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при переходе по ссылке одной из рубрик (по любой ссылке из секции "Рубрики"), я пролистываю страницу со статьями из этой рубрики вниз, а там:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подумал, что это что-то связанно с фиксированным сайдбаром. Так как у контентной части страницы задан марджин слева
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А у футера марджин не задан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я решил задать ему марджин и на этой странице стало все окей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но теперь на странице блога виджеты сместились влево и выглядят криво и убого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простите за много скринов, попытался максимально доступно изложить в чем проблема. Никак не получается исправить, помогите!

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ну как вам тут помочь, не посмотрев через инспектор, только терпения можно пожелать. Какая хоть тема используется?

Comment: Используется тема Byblos. Могу скинуть нужный фрагмент кода, только помогите :)

Answer (score 0):

Поставил эту тему на другой тестовый домен, оказалась тема изначально была косячная.

Не ставьте себе Byblos!;)